# Imaginary numbers: polar form division: switching of signs

Tags: complex-numbers

Recently I have started studying imaginary numbers. I've come at the division of complex numbers in polar form. However when I do the exercise I get almost exactly the same answer as in my textbook except in the textbook they switch the signs for reasons I don't quite understand.

The following image is the example from the textbook
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoigI.png)

division of z1 and z2

$$
z_1= \frac12 \cos⁡(3\pi / 4)+ i \sin⁡(3\pi/4)
$$
$$
z_2 =4 \cos⁡(11\pi / 6)+ i \sin⁡(11π/6)
$$

At the last step of the example the signs are switched but I don't understand why. Why do they do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first $-$ signs come from actually computing the differences. Then use the fact that $\cos$ is an even function, i.e. $\cos(-x)=\cos(x),$ and $\sin$ is odd, i.e. $\sin(-x) = -\sin x.$

Comment: Thank you, that explains it. And any idea why it switches and divides by 2 in multplication of complex numbers here (http://i.imgur.com/BfeZPvA.png) ?

Comment: @Lagastic, that looks wrong.  They're using facts from the unit circle and reference angles, but what it should be is $\cos(2\pi/3) = -\cos(\pi/3)$ and $\sin(2\pi/3) = \sin(\pi/3)$.  Check the unit circle to verify and read up on reference angles for more detailed info.

Comment: @tilper and why go to the latter form, why not just compute $$cos(2π/3) + i sin(2π/3)$$ ?

Comment: @tilper Edit: Is it because z1 and z2 are in kwadrant 1, consequently the product of z1 and z2 should also lie in kwadrant 1. π/3 lies in kwadrant 1 while 2π/3 does not ?

Comment: @Lagastic, no, that isn't why, and that's actually not true in general.  Note that the product doesn't lie in Quadrant I, it's actually in Quadrant II because the (correct) answer is $-3 + 3\sqrt{3} \, i$.  As for your original question, why not just directly compute $\cos(2\pi/3) + i\sin(2\pi/3)$, I don't know.  Personal preference I guess.

Comment: Oh ok -3 + 3sqrt(3)i  was my solution at first, didn't think there would be a mistake in the textbook so that confused me quite a bit. Thanks.